# How to Split Time and calculate time difference in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

i want to split the time and calculate time difference using sql server 2005

my default output is like this:

```
EnrollNo     AttDateFirst                          AttDateLast
111      2011-12-09 08:46:00.000          2011-12-09 08:46:00.000
112      2011-12-09 08:40:00.000          2011-12-09 17:30:00.000
302      2011-12-09 09:00:00.000          2011-12-09 18:30:00.000
303      2011-12-09 10:00:00.000          2011-12-09 18:35:00.000
```

I want my new output to be like this:

```
Enroll No     .....      FirtTime       LastTime      Time Diff
111           .....      8:46:00          8:45:00     00:00:00
112           .....      8:30:00         17:30:00      9:00:00
302           .....      9:00:00         18:30:00      9:30:00 
303           .....     10:00:00         18:35:00      8:35:00
```

Comment: First and last date are always on the same day?

Comment: yes same day. i am getting records from punch machine so user can punch any time on the same day but we want to get First and Last Punch Records and find Time Difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
select EnrollNo, convert(varchar, AttDateFirst, 8) as FirstTime,
                 convert(varchar, AttDateLast, 8) as LastTime,
                 convert(varchar, AttDateLast - AttDateFirst, 8) as [Time Diff]
from YourTable
```

to return the following results:

```
EnrollNo    FirstTime                      LastTime                       Time Diff
----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
111         08:46:00                       08:46:00                       00:00:00
112         08:30:00                       17:30:00                       09:00:00
302         09:00:00                       18:30:00                       09:30:00
303         10:00:00                       18:35:00                       08:35:00
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

> select DATEDIFF(day,2007-11-30,2007-11-20) AS NumberOfDays,
>   DATEDIFF(hour,2007-11-30,2007-11-20) AS NumberOfHours,
>   DATEDIFF(minute,2007-11-30,2007-11-20) AS NumberOfMinutes from
>   test_table

to split u can use

```
substring(AttDateFirst,charindex(' ',AttDateFirst)+1 ,
                       len(AttDateFirst)) as [FirstTime]
```