# How to remove duplicates in MySQL database by time difference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have looked at the other question with a similar topic, but it does not solve the issue I am currently having.

I have two tables:

```
users (id, name)

projects (id, user_id, image, inserted)
```

As a result of an error in Flash application in the table 'projects' there are many duplicates (one project was added several times). Between successive copies there is a few seconds time difference (less than 10 sec) and this is the only way to determine duplicates (user can add unlimited number of projects, but creating one takes at least one minute).

How to select and delete copies (and keep the original ones)?

**Edit:**

Solution posted below by Robin Castlin is almost there, but this query:

```
SELECT p2.id
FROM project AS p
INNER JOIN project AS p2
ON p.id != p2.id AND p.user_id = p2.user_id AND 
    ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(p.inserted, p2.inserted))) <= 10
GROUP BY p2.id
```

selects all copies (if user added project 5 times it gives me 5 ids). So let's reverse problem: how to select all except first/last from that group? Or only first/last one?

Comment: Eventually I've deleted copies selected by above query manually (only about 200 rows). But anyway problem is interesting and intriguing - obviously manual solution would not be possible with a larger database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_project (
    p1_id INT,
    p2_id INT
)
SELECT p.id, p2.id
FROM project AS p
INNER JOIN project AS p2
ON p.user_id = p2.user_id AND 
    ABS(TO_SECONDS(TIME_DIFF(p.inserted, p2.inserted))) <= 10;

SELECT p2_id
FROM tmp_project
WHERE p2_id NOT IN (SELECT p2_id
                    FROM tmp_project
                    GROUP BY p1_id)
GROUP BY p2_id;
```

I made it a bit more complex now. Since we would need to use the same rows 2 times to filter the 1st occurence, I create a temporary table and handle it from there after. I join all the cases, even on the same id, and then filter it by using `NOT IN` and `GROUP BY p1_id`.

**This solution could also be used if image data where identical for duplicates:**

Shouldn't the `image` field be identical in these cases?

```
SELECT id
FROM project
WHERE id NOT IN (   SELECT id
                    FROM projects
                    GROUP BY image, user_id)
```

This would make get you a list of all the duplicates that isn't the first one in the table.

---

Then take those IDs and simply

```
DELETE FROM project WHERE id IN (id1, id2, id3, ...)
```

Comment: Actually, that first query should be `GROUP BY image, user_id` - it is possible that two (or more) separate users have created projects with the same image value.

Comment: Created from timestamp where? In the MySQL? Or in the Flash?

Comment: Added another solution that might help.

Comment: I updated it more now. Ironically I ended up smashing together my 2 mentioned methods.

Answer (score 0):

Take difference between two consicutive times.

If difference is of 10 secs[According to your post] then dont add it.

Here is the question that will help you in taking exact difference between time.

[How to Split Time and calculate time difference in sql server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721984/how-to-split-time-and-calculate-time-difference-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: This partially answers the question but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @PaulGregory yeah , i know it. Exact answer would be directly posting query. but i just posted information which can guid user to make the query.